# What's a word for "almost guarantee?"

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word for "almost guarantee?" I've done some research and can't seem to find anything. Here is my sentence:

> Building a healthy lifestyle is important to *guarantee* a long life.

You can't necessarily "guarantee" that you'll live a long life. You could be the healthiest person on earth, yet die in a car accident. So, with that being said, what single word could I use that is along the lines of "almost guarantee?" I could use this sentence instead (unless a singular form of "almost guarantee" is available):

> Building a healthy lifestyle is important to guarantee a long life *to the best of one’s abilities*.

This sentence (shown above) would definitely need some restructuring, though. Any suggestions are welcome. =)

Comment: Whoever downvoted my comment, please tell me why. I did my research (and I am continuing to scour Google for an answer). What do you suggest?

Comment: Advertisers say things like "helps guarantee"

Comment: If you look at examples in any dictionary, you will find that the transferred use of ‘guarantee’ from its original meaning of a type of one element where one party to a transaction (often a vendor) assures the buyer by promising some sort of compensation if what has been sold is not as it should be.  It is a legal term.  But no advice can possibly guarantee a future event.  Nor can it ‘almost’ guarantee it.  A healthy lifestyle is a key factor in prolonging active life.

Comment: I don't get it at all. It's like saying "Eating food is important to prevent feeling hunger."

Comment: @WeatherVane It was a start. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

In *this context,* one could write **"promote"** or **"encourage."**

Promote:

> Further the progress of (something, especially a cause, venture, or aim); support or actively encourage. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/promote)]

Encourage:

> Help or stimulate (an activity, state, or view) to develop. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/encourage)]

Promote is the *better* choice (in my opinion), but both are applicable to your situation.